# Objective-C ivar BOOL not keeping value

Tags: objective-c, ios, variables

**EDIT** - apologies for the typo, i was in a rush, since i had to get out of the building but hmm... might i ask, why the downvotes? just because of a few syntax errors? i'm open to being critiqued, but please be constructive?

thanks for the constructive answers, i've given both an upvote.

=============================================

I have an iVar BOOL that i wanted to use throughout this class. i tried to initialize it to `YES`, but the first time i read it out, it is `NO`. why is that? This is strange to me because my `int`s are all retained.

in my `.mm` file I have something like this:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    BOOL myBool;
    int myInt;
}

@end

@implementation MyClass

-(id)init{
    //...
    myInt = 3;
    myBool = YES; //here i set it
    //...
    [self addObjectsToGame];
    //...
}

-(void)addObjectsToGame{
    //...
    assert(myInt == 3);
    assert(myBool);    // <---- this line would fail
    //...
}

@end
```

i get that i can use a @property with assign, but why does this iVar not retain it's value??

**EDIT**

okay yeah, wow, something is really messed up here... i tried to replace it with `@property` and it's still not working. i then tried to "find all in project" for the variable `myBool` and i'm NOT changing it anywhere else

Note: i'm using cocos2d, but i dont think that should affect anything

Comment: Are you sure that you are not missing a second `@end` before the `@implementation`?

Comment: I don't recognize that syntax for declaring `addObjectsToGame` where you have the parentheses after the method name. And you're not invoking this as `[self addObjectsToGame]`. Clearly this isn't a standard Objective-C file. Is this Objective-C++?

Comment: can u give us the real code? `-(void)addObjectsToGame()` is not valid obj-c

Comment: ah. you're right, it wasn't objective-C code, i just typed it up in an editor, because the real code is REALLY long. but here's what i did - i tried to use XCode's "find all in project" for the variable "myBool", and there was only 1 instance where i was actively changing the value of it - in the `init`.... and when i went to `NSLog("%@",myBool?@"true":@"false");` after the `init`, the output would give me `false`... that's why i was so confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed Objective-C syntax for you and everything works as expected

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    BOOL myBool;
    int myInt;
}
-(void)addObjectsToGame;
@end

@implementation MyClass

-(id)init{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        myInt = 3;
        myBool = YES; //here i set it
        [self addObjectsToGame];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)addObjectsToGame{
    assert(myInt == 3);
    assert(myBool);
    NSLog(@"OK");
}

@end


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        [MyClass new];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this iVar **will** retain it's value, as long as you don't do anything else to mess it up

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    BOOL myBool;
    int myInt;
}
@end

@implementation MyClass

-(id)init{
    //...
    myInt = 3;
    myBool = YES; //here i set it
    //...
    [self addObjectsToGame];
    //...
    return self;
}

-(void)addObjectsToGame{
    //...
    assert(myInt == 3);
    assert(myBool);    // <---- this line would fail
    //...
    NSLog(@"didn't fail");
}

@end
```

This code didn't fail

Answer (score 0):

oh wow, i'm such a noob on iOS -

all `BOOL` values initialize to `NO` (rather than random), and the reason i kept getting `NO` was because i had been using the `BOOL` right before assigning it, and also that i had made it `non-atomic` (though this won't matter most of the time)

this was the real reason; however, i'm going to accept someone else's answer seeing this is such a trivial mistake in the making

Comment: "rather than random" - those are C-style auto variables that are stack-allocated. Instance variables are zeroed by the runtime when an instance is created.